# Seeing Multiple Partition for same LUN

Tags: centos6, lvm, multipath, device-mapper

Anyone knows why I am seeing multiple device for the same LUN?I checked with storage team they only exposed 360000970000196801239533036304532 for this server but why I am seeing these many partition(p1..p7)

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8 Jan 20 16:30 360000970000196801239533036304532 -> ../dm-39
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8 Jan 20 16:30 360000970000196801239533036304532p1 -> ../dm-64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8 Jan 20 16:30 360000970000196801239533036304532p2 -> ../dm-65
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8 Jan 20 16:30 360000970000196801239533036304532p3 -> ../dm-66
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8 Jan 20 16:30 360000970000196801239533036304532p4 -> ../dm-67
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8 Jan 20 16:30 360000970000196801239533036304532p5 -> ../dm-69
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8 Jan 20 16:30 360000970000196801239533036304532p6 -> ../dm-70
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8 Jan 20 16:30 360000970000196801239533036304532p7 -> ../dm-71
```

AFAIK I understand devices in dev mapper are created early in the boot process and /dev/dm-n are for internal use only

Even in the output of fdisk I see those 2 devices

```
Disk /dev/mapper/360000970000196801239533036304532: 515.4 GB, 515396075520 bytes


Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

/dev/mapper/360000970000196801239533036304532p1               1       62661   503316479+  ee  GPT

```
Disk /dev/mapper/360000970000196801239533036304536: 515.4 GB, 515396075520 bytes
```

When I am trying to create Physical Volume on original LUN it fails due to this error

```
pvcreate /dev/mapper/360000970000196801239533036304532
Device /dev/mapper/360000970000196801239533036304532 not found (or ignored by filtering).
```

I already checked lvm.conf there is nothing defined in filtering

System  info

```
cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.8 (Final)

device-mapper-multipath-0.4.9-93.el6.x86_64
device-mapper-persistent-data-0.6.2-0.1.rc7.el6.x86_64
device-mapper-multipath-libs-0.4.9-93.el6.x86_64
device-mapper-libs-1.02.117-7.el6_8.1.x86_64
device-mapper-event-libs-1.02.117-7.el6_8.1.x86_64
device-mapper-event-1.02.117-7.el6_8.1.x86_64
lvm2-2.02.143-7.el6_8.1.x86_64
device-mapper-1.02.117-7.el6_8.1.x86_64
lvm2-libs-2.02.143-7.el6_8.1.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

When device is connected, kpartx creates DM devices for found partitions. I see fdisk found at least one partition, but it may be incorrect about remaining. As fdisk man page on RHEL7 says: *fdisk does not understand GUID partition tables (GPTs) and it is not designed for large partitions.  In these cases, use the more advanced GNU parted(8)*, I guess it is the same on CentOS6. Use either `gdisk` or `parted` as suggested to see if there are multiple partitions.

If you are sure you want to get rid of all partitions you could first try `wipefs -a` on the device.

Also make sure multipath_component_detection in lvm.conf is set to 1.